# How to get parameters from the method and display a matrix in the HTML through JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

The JSP have a method that creates a matrix:

```
<%!
int[][] rndMatrix(int M, int N) {
Random rnd = new Random();
int matrix[][] = new int[M][N];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  matrix[i][j] = 1;
}
matrix[i][rnd.nextInt(N)] = 0;
}
%>
```

I can not figure out how to get the parameters of the method itself, which would have to ask them and to bring in html.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to access the parameters you pass to the method. In that case, you already have that in the return value

`M == return_matrix.length`

`N == return_matrix[0].length`

Comment: You do not quite understand me.
I have a form, inside it has a 2 input, 1 is  M input, input 2 is N
I need to pass parameters M, N of the input method

Comment: Then you need to send that a backend server to process and send back the data or just do it in javascript on the client